# How can I dispose of gravel?

Tags: landscaping, disposal, gravel

The previous owner of my house decided to plant two large junipers in front of the house and fill around them with ~1-2" diameter gravel.  I've already taken out the junipers but now I am left to deal with about 2 to 3 yards of gravel that's been sitting there cementing for the last 30 years.  I'll be able to pick axe and shovel most of it out but I have no clue how to get rid of it.  I doubt anyone will takes it for free, it's mostly mixed and compressed with years of juniper waste and weeds.  Anyone know of a good way to get rid of this stuff without paying huge dumpster rental fees?

Comment: You really don't have anything to lose by trying craigslist...

Answer (score 8):

Three options I can think of right now:

Craigslist, Local newspaper and Freecycle

Our paper has a free $50 and under section which still gets traffic even in this digital age.

You might be pleasantly surprised by someone willing to come pick that gravel up.  Folks looking for fill material might not care at all that what it is mixed in.

Freecycle is pretty good for finding a new owner of things unwanted.

Another option - put a sign out in front of your place - "Free Gravel - You Haul".
I've gotten rid of all sort of things with the "Free" sign.  Of course, you might have a few "squirrels" show up to your place with any of these options but most people are friendly enough.

Another option might be to just solarize/kill off the weeds and cover it it with soil or mulch.  Not sure what you ultimate plans are for this area but perhaps if you are going to plant there anyway you can leave it in place an just cover it up.

Personally, I'd see if someone from craigslist, the local paper or freecycle was willing to take it off for you.

Comment: If you lived near me I would take it - there's a puddle in my driveway that needs about 10 wheelbarrows of gravel and that's not an amount that's feasible to buy.